# Custom format view issue with UK date format in SharePoint Online

Tags: json, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I have applied view formatting and also column formatting using JSON to a number of views on a list that are displaying calculated columns returning data type, Date and Time. The dates were being displayed correctly on the custom formatted views for a number of weeks until very recently it stopped working. The dates are now being displayed in the US format or as invalid, even though the locale settings on the site is set to UK.

Not too sure what could be causing the issue. I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance.

Calculated Column (A&R stage deadline):

=([Total Days Clock Stopped]+[SAR Start Date]+27)

Data Type: Date and Time
Date and Time Format: Date only

```
{
  "schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/view-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "ms-borderColor-neutralLight"
    },
    "style": {
      "width": "65%",
      "flex-direction": "column",
      "align-items": "stretch",
      "box-sizing": "border-box",
      "border-width": "1px",
      "border-style": "solid",
      "margin-bottom": "10px"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "display": "flex",
          "flex-wrap": "wrap",
          "align-items": "center",
          "box-sizing": "border-box"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "style": {
              "flex": " 1 0 300px"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {},
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-font-xl"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1.5em",
                      "color": "Green",
                      "margin": "10px 0",
                      "padding": "0 20px"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Title]"
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-sPlus"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1.5em",
                      "margin": "8px 0"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "inline-block"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "display": "inline-block",
                              "margin-right": "18px",
                              "padding": "0 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "Data Subject:"
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                              "display": "block",
                              "padding": "8px 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "[$Data_x0020_subject]"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-sPlus"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1em",
                      "margin": "8px 0"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "inline-block"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "display": "inline-block",
                              "margin-right": "18px",
                              "padding": "0 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "Academy:"
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                              "display": "block",
                              "padding": "8px 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "[$Academy.lookupValue]"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "div",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontSize-sPlus"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "line-height": "1em",
                      "margin": "8px 0"
                    },
                    "children": [
                      {
                        "elmType": "div",
                        "style": {
                          "display": "inline-block"
                        },
                        "children": [
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "attributes": {
                              "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                            },
                            "style": {
                              "display": "inline-block",
                              "margin-right": "18px",
                              "padding": "0 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "Additional SAR Managers:"
                          },
                          {
                            "elmType": "span",
                            "style": {
                              "display": "block",
                              "padding": "8px 20px"
                            },
                            "txtContent": "[$Additional_x0020_SAR_x0020_Manag.title]"
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "flex": "0 0 170px",
                  "display": "flex",
                  "flex-direction": "row"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "editProps"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Edit/ View",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "color": "Green",
                      "width": "100px",
                      "height": "32px",
                      "margin": "20px 0 10px 5px"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "executeFlow",
                      "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"aac77602-dead-438c-b85d-d4e93fb27efc\"}"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Complete Stage",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "color": "Green",
                      "width": "145px",
                      "height": "32px",
                      "margin": "20px 0 10px 5px",
                      "display": "=if([$A_x0026_R_x0020_Status] != 'Completed', '', 'none')"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "executeFlow",
                      "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"6621b694-3fd4-48b3-9586-7b5250397efe\"}"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Stop the Clock",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "color": "Green",
                      "width": "145px",
                      "height": "32px",
                      "margin": "20px 0 10px 5px",
                      "display": "=if([$Clock_x0020_Stopped] == 'No', '', 'none')"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "executeFlow",
                      "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"d910384c-3f50-4a1d-a53c-47d9a94c3ada\"}"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Start the Clock",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "color": "Green",
                      "width": "145px",
                      "height": "32px",
                      "margin": "20px 0 10px 5px",
                      "display": "=if([$Clock_x0020_Stopped] == 'Yes', '', 'none')"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "button",
                    "customRowAction": {
                      "action": "executeFlow",
                      "actionParams": "{\"id\": \"d9cbbb5b-54d1-498a-a25d-e9cb072ea696\"}"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Cancel/ Withdraw",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontColor-themePrimary ms-fontColor-themeDarker--hover"
                    },
                    "style": {
                      "color": "Green",
                      "width": "145px",
                      "height": "32px",
                      "margin": "20px 0 10px 5px"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-fontSize-sPlus ms-bgColor-neutralLighter"
            },
            "style": {
              "padding": "25px 20px",
              "line-height": "1.4em",
              "flex-direction": "row",
              "justify-content": "space-between"
            },
            "children": [
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {},
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "A&R Start Date: "
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "inline-block"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString([$A_x0026_R_x0020_Start_x0020_Date])"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "A&R Deadline: "
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "inline-block",
                      "color": "=if([$A_x0026_R_x0020_stage_x0020_dead] <= @now, 'Red', '')"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "=toLocaleDateString([$A_x0026_R_x0020_stage_x0020_dead])"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "margin": "0 0px"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "SAR Deadline: "
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "inline-block"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Due_x0020_Date]"
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                "elmType": "div",
                "style": {
                  "margin": "0 0px"
                },
                "children": [
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "attributes": {
                      "class": "ms-fontWeight-semibold"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "Clock Stopped: "
                  },
                  {
                    "elmType": "span",
                    "style": {
                      "display": "inline-block",
                      "color": "=if([$Clock_x0020_Stopped] == 'Yes', 'Red', 'Green')"
                    },
                    "txtContent": "[$Clock_x0020_Stopped]"
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd better share your json format and calculate column formula.

Comment: @Amos_MSFT, Is this everything you needed? Please let me know if you need further information. Thanks